# Aligning annotations using hfill

Tags: layout, hfill

Please excuse my beginner question, I am pretty inexperienced with LaTeX.
My question is quite similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547999/latex-hfill-to-a-certain-width).

I have lines of maths followed by annotations commenting on the maths on the same line. For example,

```
\begin{align*}
v_2(x_3'y_2') &= v_2(x_3') + v_2(y_2') \hfill{} \text{(by (ii') of valuation properties)}  \\
            &> v_2(y_3') + v_2(y_2') \hfill{} \text{(since } (x_3,y_3) \in S_3 \text{)} \\
            &\geq v_2(y_3') +v_2(x_2') \hfill{} \text{(since } (x_2,y_2) \in S_2 \text{)} \\
            &= v_2(x_2'y_3') \hfill{} \text{(by (ii') of valuation properties)}
\end{align*}
```

The `\hfill{}` needs to be replaced by a different command as my existing code isn't producing the output I would like. I want the annotations to be pushed as far to the right, while still remaining on the same line as the relevant maths.
What is the simplest way I could do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you don't need to number the equations, you can use `\tag`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
v_2(x_3'y_2') &= v_2(x_3') + v_2(y_2') \tag{by (ii') of valuation properties}  \\
            &> v_2(y_3') + v_2(y_2') \tag{since \((x_3,y_3) \in S_3\)} \\
            &\geq v_2(y_3') +v_2(x_2') \tag{since \((x_2,y_2) \in S_2\)} \\
            &= v_2(x_2'y_3') \tag{by (ii') of valuation properties}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you.